# Insert values from different rows into one row and multiple columns grouping by specific value of column x

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Sorry if Im not clear in title, I have some language problems. I have a table (quite big) like

```
   Person    value    Letter
------------------------------------------
    Tom      value1     A      
    Tom      value2     T         
    Ann      value1     F    
    Ann      value2     R
    Ann      value3     Y 
    Jim      value3     W
```

I would like to shorten it into:

```
   Person    value1    value2    value3
------------------------------------------
    Tom        A        T          (null)
    Ann        F        R            Y   
    Jim     (null)    (null)         W
```

Something like listagg, but into different columns. Looks simple but I'm stuck...

edit: There are 8 values, not just 3, I wanted made it simplier, values don't repeat for the same person (but can be null/not appear))

Comment: Are there always only three possible values?

Comment: No, about 7 with 3 I would simply write down all combinations :)

Comment: Is there a unique constraint on the person and value columns? I.e. could Tom have more than one row with the same value name? If so, what would you want the output to be like?

Comment: Yes it's unique. If there is, say, a value3, its only one for Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option: the idea is to use an aggregate function (such as `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`). As your sample data contain only 3 values, that's what I did as well - you'd use 5 more lines like this (including them from line #13 onward).

Note that lines #1 - 8 represent your sample data; you already have them stored in the table so you wouldn't be typing that. Code you actually need begins at line #9.

```
SQL> with test (person, value, letter) as
  2    (select 'Tom', 'val1', 'A' from dual union all
  3     select 'Tom', 'val2', 'T' from dual union all
  4     select 'Ann', 'val1', 'F' from dual union all
  5     select 'Ann', 'val2', 'R' from dual union all
  6     select 'Ann', 'val3', 'Y' from dual union all
  7     select 'Jim', 'val3', 'W' from dual
  8    )
  9  select
 10    person,
 11    max(decode(value, 'val1', letter)) value1,
 12    max(decode(value, 'val2', letter)) value2,
 13    max(decode(value, 'val3', letter)) value3
 14  from test
 15  group by person
 16  order by person;

PERSON VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3
------ ------ ------ ------
Ann    F      R      Y
Jim                  W
Tom    A      T

SQL>
```